# Where can I find a new place to live?

Tags: fallen-london

When I first, let's say arrived, in Fallen London, real estate opportunities were scarce for someone of my... standing.

I certainly wasn't too choosy back then, but now that I feel a little more settled, this old attic is looking more and more dingy to me.

**Where might I acquire new lodgings?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List of lodgings is here: http://echobazaar.wikidot.com/available-lodgings.

I went for the "Rooms above a bookshop" - IIRC, using the Tales of Terror in your inventory creates a key for the rooms, which appears as a story option for you. I discovered this when mousing over items in inventory, some of which are usable by clicking to create new things.